# How to archive multiple files in sftp directory and move those files to an other directory?

Tags: sftp, mulesoft, mule4, mule-component

I have an sftp folder where 200 files will be dropped on daily basis.
I need to archive these files and move them to another sftp folder in 1 shot instead of moving 1 file at time.
Basically, I want to archive/move the files into a separate folder without using foreach approach of archiving and writing file by file.
Is there an approach that I can follow to achieve that.

Thx

Comment: Seems like the default behavior of the Mule SFTP connector. Have you tried it? Doesn't it meet your expectations? You should be more specific in your question and provide more details.

Comment: I have amended the question with some more details.

Answer (score 0):

The [SFTP Listener source](https://docs.mulesoft.com/sftp-connector/1.6/sftp-documentation#listener) has a `Move To Directory` configuration to set a directory to move the files received to that directory.